# Can we measure $x$ and $p_x$ simultaneously by measuring $p_y$ and $y$ as well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, quantum-measurements

Suppose our plan is to measure experimentally the position $(x,y)$ in the plane and the momentum $(p_{x}, p_{y})$ of a quantum particle. Assuming the canonical commutation relation between $x$ and $p_{x}$, we will bypass so to speak the law by performing the following sequence of measurements:
$$ x \rightarrow p_{y}\rightarrow p_{x} \rightarrow y$$
Since, for each successive measurement the commutators vanish i.e $[x,p_y]=[p_y,p_x]=[p_x, y]=0$, we can make the measurement of the above mentioned quantities without affecting the system. Is this a viable way to measure the position and momentum simultaneously?

Answer (score 4):

Even if measurement of $x$ puts your system in a state with definite $x$, as soon as you measure $p_x$ this will no longer be the case. The same is true about $p_y$ and $y$. So no, you still cannot use this to produce a state with definite $x$ and $p_x$.

Of course there exist states with definite $(x,p_y)$, definite $(p_y,p_x)$, or definite $(p_x,y)$, but that doesn't help us here. There do not exist any states in QM where both $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ are both $0$, as this would violate the HUP. There is no way around this.

Comment: but the operators are commuting so the operators in each step are compatible.

Comment: @user11937 That doesn't matter. The fact that $[x,p_x]\neq0$ means that there exist no states with definite $x$ and $p_x$, no matter how you do the measurements.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might misunderstand the difference between the commutation (or not) of observables and *measurement* of those observables.

If two observables do not commute, it means that there is no state that is an eigenstate of both observables. For example, there is no state vector $|x,p_x\rangle$ such that

$$X|x,p_x\rangle = x|x,p_x\rangle$$

and

$$P_x|x,p_x\rangle = p_x|x,p_x\rangle$$

Thus, the problem isn't a measurement problem, the problem is that such a state (with definite $x$ position and definite $x$ momentum) *does not exist*.

Now, a postulate of QM is that, just after a *measurement* of an observable, the state of the particle (system) is an eigenstate of that observable.

In your example, you begin with a state vector $|x,p_y\rangle$ that satisfies

$$X|x,p_y\rangle = x|x,p_y\rangle$$

and

$$P_y|x,p_y\rangle = p_y|x,p_y\rangle$$

But the state represented by this state vector is not an eigenstate of $P_x$ thus, upon measurement of $P_x$, the state vector is no longer $|x,p_y\rangle$.

Comment: this is what I don' t understand: If I measure $x$ then obviously $p_{x}$ is affected. But $[p_{y},x]=0$ so we can subsequently measure $p_{y}$ after $x$ because they are in the same eigenstate. But because $[p_{y}, p_{x}]=0$  and thus it follows that $p_{y}$ has to also be in the same eigenstate as $p_{x}$ because they commute. It follows now, that we can both measure $p_{y}$ with absolute precision because it is in the same eigenstate as $x$ and we cannot measure it because it is in the same eigenstates as $p_{x}$.

Comment: I could make my above comment into a question if you don't mind

Comment: @user11937, sorry, but I don't follow your reasoning at all. Maybe it will be clear to me what you're trying to say later.

Comment: I made a question out of my comment https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/562731/a-question-regarding-the-commutators-of-operators

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we can consider the state $|\psi\rangle_{xy}$ in the $xy$ plane to be a tensor product of two one-dimensional states, $|\psi\rangle_x$ and $|\psi\rangle_y$. These states are independent: measuring one will not affect the other. Let's conduct your measurements in sequence. First, we have the state
$$
|\psi\rangle_x\otimes |\psi\rangle_y
$$
We then conduct a $y$ position measurement, causing the $y$ ket to collapse to a position eigenket $y = q$. The state is now
$$
|\psi\rangle_x\otimes |y = q\rangle_y
$$
Next, we measure the $x$ momentum, getting $p_x = m$, and putting our state in the form
$$
|p_x = m\rangle_x\otimes |y = q\rangle_y
$$
Next, we measure the $y$ momentum. It's true that this measurement commutes with our $p_x$ measurement: our ket $|\psi\rangle_{xy}$ is really the tensor product $|\psi\rangle_x\otimes |\psi\rangle_y$, and measuring the momentum of $|\psi\rangle_x$ should have no effect on the momentum of $|\psi\rangle_y$. But that doesn't mean that the measurement doesn't affect the state $|\psi\rangle_y$. The measurement has the same effect that it would on *any* state: collapsing it to an eigenstate. After the measurement, our state becomes
$$
|p_x = m\rangle_x\otimes |p_y = n\rangle_y
$$
for some measured $y$ momentum $n$. The $y$ position is lost, and we now have only the momentum.

The reason for this is that *independent kets don't care about what the other ket is doing.* Sure, from your perspective, you conducted the measurements $x, p_y, p_x, y$, each of which individually commute. But from the perspective of the $y$ ket, you only conducted two measurements: $y$ and $p_y$, which clearly don't commute. So simultaneous eigenstates are impossible.

Answering your question from another angle: while your suggested measurements commute *adjacently*
$$
xp_yp_xy = p_yxp_xy = xp_xp_yy = xp_yyp_x
$$
they do not commute *in general*
$$
xp_yp_xy \ne yp_yp_xx
$$
indicating that a simultaneous eigenstate of the four operators is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] by performing the following sequence of measurements: $x \rightarrow p_y \rightarrow p_x \rightarrow y $ [...]

Corresponding to these four stages of the sequence of measurements we can consider four generally distinct states (sets of observational data), $\psi_1, \psi_2, \psi_3$ and $\psi_4$, such that for any arbitrary state $\phi$ holds

$$ \langle \phi | \hat x \, \psi_1 \rangle \, \langle \psi_1 | \psi_1 \rangle = \langle \phi | \psi_1 \rangle \, \langle \psi_1 | \hat x \, \psi_1 \rangle, \text{ and abbreviating } x := \frac{\langle \psi_1 | \, \hat x \, \psi_1 \rangle}{\langle \psi_1 | \psi_1 \rangle}, $$

$$ \langle \phi | \hat p_y \, \psi_2 \rangle \, \langle \psi_2 | \psi_2 \rangle = \langle \phi | \psi_2 \rangle \, \langle \psi_2 | \hat p_y \, \psi_2 \rangle, \text{ and abbreviating } p_y := \frac{\langle \psi_2 | \, \hat p_y \, \psi_2 \rangle}{\langle \psi_2 | \psi_2 \rangle}, $$

$$ \langle \phi | \hat p_x \, \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle = \langle \phi | \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \psi_3 | \hat p_x \, \psi_3 \rangle, \text{ and abbreviating } p_x := \frac{\langle \psi_3 | \, \hat p_x \, \psi_3 \rangle}{\langle \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle}, $$

$$ \langle \phi | \hat y \, \psi_4 \rangle \, \langle \psi_4 | \psi_4 \rangle = \langle \phi | \psi_4 \rangle \, \langle \psi_4 | \hat y \, \psi_4 \rangle, \text{ and abbreviating } y := \frac{\langle \psi_4 | \, \hat y \, \psi_4 \rangle}{\langle \psi_4 | \psi_4 \rangle}. $$

> [...] the commutators vanish i.e $[x, p_y] = [p_y, p_x] = [p_x, y] = 0$ [...]

The relevant commutators are of course not between the result values (of the individual stages of measurements), but between the measurement operators (which are applied, stage by stage); i.e.

$$ [\hat x, \hat p_y] = [\hat p_y, \hat p_x] = [\hat p_x, \hat y] = 0,$$

while

$$ [\hat x, \hat p_x] = [\hat y, \hat p_y] =  \mathbf i \, \hbar \neq 0.$$

> Since, for each successive measurement the commutators vanish [...]

The vanishing commutators have to do with compatibility of measurement operators, and thus with the possibility of interchanging the order of measurement stages. For instance, from $ [\hat x, \hat p_y] = 0 $ we have for state $\psi_2$ and any arbitrary state $\phi$:

$$ \langle \phi | \, (\hat p_y \, \hat x) \, \psi_2 \rangle = \langle \phi | \, (\hat x \, \hat p_y) \, \psi_2 \rangle = p_y \, \langle \phi | \, \hat x \, \psi_2 \rangle.$$

This, by itself, does neither guarantee, nor does it rule out, that

$$\langle \phi | \, \hat x \, \psi_2 \rangle \, \langle \psi_2 | \psi_2 \rangle = \langle \phi | \psi_2 \rangle \, \langle \psi_2 | \, \hat x \, \psi_2 \rangle \tag{*}.$$

Accordingly, we can distinguish two cases:
Either condition $(\ast)$ fails and there is no specific $x$-value attributable  to state $\psi_2$ at all -- then the supposed plan apparently fails already at measurement stage 2.

Or condition $(\ast)$ holds, and we continue to consider measurement stage 3; i.e. state $\psi_3$ with $\langle \phi | \hat p_x \, \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle = \langle \phi | \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \psi_3 | \hat p_x \, \psi_3 \rangle$ from above.
But the application of operator $\hat x$ to such a state $\psi_3$ is undefined (or, at least, doesn't result in any arbitrary state $\phi$ at all)! For, suppose to the contrary that we could specify $\phi \equiv \hat x \, \psi_3$. This yields (due to the measurement operators $\hat x$ and $\hat p_x$ being self-adjoint):

$$\langle \psi_3 | (\hat x \, \hat p_x) \, \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle = \langle \hat x \, \psi_3 | \hat p_x \, \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle = \langle \hat x \, \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \psi_3 | \hat p_x \, \psi_3 \rangle = \langle \psi_3 | \hat x \, \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \hat p_x \, \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle = \langle \psi_3 | (\hat p_x \, \hat x) \, \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle.$$

But on the other hand with the above commutator holds:

$$\langle \psi_3 | (\hat x \, \hat p_x) \, \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle = \langle \psi_3 | (\hat p_x \, \hat x) \, \psi_3 \rangle \, \langle \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle + \mathbf i \, \hbar \, (\langle \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle)^2.$$

Consequently: $ \mathbf i \, \hbar \, (\langle \psi_3 | \psi_3 \rangle)^2 = 0$, i.e. contrary to stage 3 of the measurement sequence having been carried out and corresponding relevant observational data $\psi_3$ having been obtained at all.
Thus, the supposed plan fails in any case:
If a sequence of measurements has been carried out involving application of conjugate measurement operators then the values thus obtained are not together characterizing the same state.